# Is application of the ES6 spread operator on Objects a standard ECMAScript specification?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[MDN defines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the usage of the spread operator as acting for arrays only.

For example, a proper usage for the spread operator looks like

```
var parts = ['shoulders', 'knees'];
var lyrics = ['head', ...parts, 'and', 'toes']; // ["head", "shoulders", "knees", "and", "toes"]
```

where we have applied the spread operator on the *array* `parts`.

But [in the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html), they use the spread operator on *objects* like so

```
var props = {}; 
props.foo = x; 
props.bar = y; 
var component = <Component {...props} />;
```

If I actually try to do this in the console, I receive a TypeError

```
var a = {b:1,c:2}
console.log(...a);  // TypeError
```

My questions are:

- Is using the spread operator over objects a standard implemented in the spec (and this use case was somehow omitted from the MDN docs and the console example I tried to show was not done correctly thus giving the TypeError)?
- If not a standard implementation, what is going on under the hood to allow the React component to finesse the spread operator to act in the non-standard method that it does (i.e. acting on objects), and suppress the TypeError that would inevitably arise when doing so?

Comment: It's not the standard yet: https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread + https://github.com/tc39/ecma262

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I actually try to do this in the console, I receive a TypeError

You are confusing some things here (can't blame you if they all look similar).

In your example,

```
console.log(...a);
```

the `...a` is **not** an application of object spread. It's sometimes referred to as [*spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (even though this one specifically doesn't really have a name), which is standardized in ES2015. It is used in function calls as last "argument" and only works on *iterables*. Objects are not iterables and hence you get the error.

*Object spread*, which currently is a [proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread), is only used in *object literals*:

```
var foo = {x: 42};
var bar = {y: 21, ...foo}; // equivalent to Object.assign({y: 21}, foo);
```

> what is going on under the hood

The use inside [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) (`<Component {...props} />`) is a again something slightly different, its a *JSXSpreadAttribute*, but it does desugar to object spread. If you [try it out in Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=%3CComponent%20foo%3D%7Btrue%7D%20%7B...props%7D%20%2F%3E) you can see what it is converted to:

```
var _extends = Object.assign || /* polyfill */;

React.createElement(Component, _extends({ foo: true }, props));
```

Answer (score 3):

The spread operator is being standardized at the moment, and so it cannot be used with just ES2015. At this moment it is a proposal in stage 2 of the process and will presumably be in the ES2017 spec.

https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread

It already can be leveraged by using some additional babel plugins when transpiling to ES5. This is what is used in the samples you mentioned.

http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/

Comment: "not yet in ES6" --- there is no such a thing as ES6, never was and never will be.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? My usage of the term ES6? The react docs use babel to transpile from what most people see as ES6 or ES2015 to the previous version. In my opinion this is hard for beginners to understand that the samples sometimes require to use further plugins for "not yet standardized" features to get the code transpiled (although I like to be able to use this syntax already).

Comment: Yep."not yet in ES6" implies it will some time appear there, while ES6 as a standard name never existed and these days it's not recommended to use it at all (since it's weird to refer to imaginary standards). The already accepted standard is ES2015, ES2016 is in progress and the current stages are the proposals for the ES2017.

Comment: Now it's much better. It will not be a part of ES2016 either as well.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that "it will be in ES6 later", but that it is not yet usable by just transpiling what was called ES6 to ES5. Edited my answer to clarify this. Thanks!